# Why is my variable not altering after changing once

Tags: node.js, express, callback, request

I am making a simple web-application that fetches the definition of a word using an API. There's definitely nothing wrong with the API keys because the application semi-works - Once i search for a word for the first time it will give back a result however, on the second try and onwards the definition doesn't change (The definition matches the first word instead of the latest one).

I'm thinking it has something to do with scopes and constants but I tried that already (Change var to let or const). I've read online about that callback functions are Asynchronous but I don't think that's the issue at all.

```js
app.get('/definition/:word', (req, res) => {
    if (word !== req.params.word) {
        console.log("If statement");
        word = req.params.word;
        console.log(word);
        word = word.toLowerCase();
    }

    options.path += '/' + language_code + '/' + word + '?fields=definitions' +
    '&strictMatch=true';

    url += options.path;
    console.log(options.path);

    request(url, options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            res.redirect('/error');
        } else {
            let statusCode = (response.statusCode);
            console.log(statusCode);
            if (statusCode === 200) {
                let data = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(definition);
                definition = String(data.results[0].lexicalEntries[0].entries[0].senses[0].definitions);
                console.log(definition);
                res.render('definition', {
                    wordTitle: word,
                    definitions: definition
                });
            } else {
                res.redirect('/error');
            }

        }
    });
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

    console.log("Post");


    word = String(req.body.Word);
    word = word.toLowerCase();

    console.log(word);

    res.redirect('/definition/' + word);
});
```

EDIT 1:
**full index.js source code:** https://github.com/NikodemBieniek/dictionary/blob/myfeature/server/index.js

Comment: You're not being very descriptive, what variable doesn't change? `word`? From what I see in your code you use global variables everywhere. Do not use global variables anywhere, **only** use `let` and `const`. Which means that you wont be able to change your global `word` variable, which is the right thing to do. APIs are not supposed to hold any kind of user's state, if you want something like it use cookies, web storage or a database.
TL;DR; It's not part of your code that's not buggy, it's all of your code. Do not use global variables.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show my full code:
https://github.com/NikodemBieniek/dictionary/blob/myfeature/server/index.js

Comment: I've declared the variables at the top using let

Comment: The variable that doesn't change is 'definition'. Variable 'word' changes every time but not definition

Comment: have you actually checked that `data.results[0].lexicalEntries[0].entries[0].senses[0].definitions` isn't equal to the value? maybe debug / log it aswell

Comment: Sorry if i'm being very vague, this is my first time asking a question here. Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/BmY0Cz8g
As you can see, the data object definitely exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with  below line of code

```
    options.path += '/' + language_code + '/' + word + '?fields=definitions' +
    '&strictMatch=true';
```

So first time when you make API call and pass  a param as  'XYZ'
the value in option.path will be

`/en-gb/xyz?fields=definition&strictMatch=true`

The second time you make API call and pass a param as 'PQR' the value in option.path will be

`/en-gb/xyz?fields=definition&strictMatch=true/en-gb/pqr?fields=definition&strictMatch=true`

Because you are doing string concatination.

The possible fix can be

```
app.get('/definition/:word', (req, res) => {
    if (word !== req.params.word) {
        console.log("If statement");
        word = req.params.word;
        console.log(word);
        word = word.toLowerCase();




    }
   const options = {
    host: 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com',
    port: '443',
    path: '/api/v2/entries',
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'app_id': process.env.APP_ID,
        'app_key': process.env.APP_KEY,
    }
};

    options.path += '/' + language_code + '/' + word + '?fields=definitions' +
    '&strictMatch=true';

    let url = `${options.host}${options.path}`;

    request(url, options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            res.redirect('/error');
        } else {
            let statusCode = (response.statusCode);
            console.log(statusCode);
            if (statusCode === 200) {
                let data = JSON.parse(body);
                definition = String(data.results[0].lexicalEntries[0].entries[0].senses[0].definitions);
                res.render('definition', {
                    wordTitle: word,
                    definitions: definition
                });
            } else {
                res.redirect('/error');
            }

        }
    });
});
```

> Remove option and URL declared on line 12 and 26